# Using addListener to an element that would be created later

Tags: javascript

I get an error '.addListener is not a function' upon trying this:

```
if(document.getElementById("id")){
   document.getElementById("id").addListener('click', function(){alert("ok");});
}
```

This element 'id' comes into picture when the entire document gets loaded, and I am using it in the middle of the documents construction. So, I did this:

```
window.onload = function(){
                if(document.getElementById("id")){
                   document.getElementById("id").addListener('click', function(){
                   alert("ok");
                   });
                }
}
```

The error is gone now, but the element 'id' does nothing upon being clicked.
How to make it clickable?

Comment: `addListener` is not the same as `addEventListener `. Are you sure your `window.onload` handler is running?

Comment: As the error already says. There's no such thing as `.addListener()` only `.addEventListener()` -> Typo

Comment: @CertainPerformance - I guess that's the problem, window.onload is not working...I'm trying, will post if i'm able to do something.

Comment: @Andreas - Yes, sir, that was the typo. Edited the question.

Comment: question still has the "typo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may be assigning to `window.onload` more than once. If you do this, only the *last* callback assigned to it will run. Use `addEventListener` instead, so that prior assignments to `onload` do not conflict with later assignments to `onload`.

You can also listen for `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load`, allowing the listener to be attached faster:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  const elm = document.getElementById("id");
  if(!elm){
    return;
  }
  elm.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert("ok");
  });
});
```

Best to never assign to an `.on-` property unless you're certain it will never be assigned to again (or unless you're certain it should only ever have one listener).

Comment: It worked nicely, Sir. Very new to JS, finding it a bit hard. From your answer, I am concluding these 2  things - `1.`window.onload() should be used only once( to avoid conflict in case of re-assignment), window.addEventListener() can be used multiple times. `2.` DOMContentLoaded should be used for attaching listener faster.

Comment: Yes, all of those are correct. `load` will wait for *everything* on the page to load, including images and other things that aren't necessary - `DOMContentLoaded` fires as soon as the DOM is finished being initially populated.

Answer (score 1):

Because the element is added later in the dom, you can not attach a listener this way.
What you should do is to attach a listener on the document that will 'filter' the events, so elements added later on in the dom will still be able to fire your events. Try the code below:

```
 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'id'){
          //do something
     }
 });
```

Now anytime anything is clicked on the dom, this listener will await for an element with id='id' to execute your code, otherwise it will not do anything. This method is called 
"event delegation", look it up for more info!

Comment: Thank you very much for suggesting and explaining event-delegation.